# Codename one - Form.initLaf throws random "Illegal Access" errors

Tags: error-handling, codenameone, illegalaccessexception

in my app, I get "IllegalAccess" errors, at seemingly random places and times.
The only thing in common is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor3 cannot access its superclass sun.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl
at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:55)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
**at com.codename1.ui.Form.initLaf(Form.java:969)**
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.initLaf(Dialog.java:499)
at com.codename1.ui.Component.<init>(Component.java:687)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.<init>(Container.java:187)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.<init>(Container.java:199)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.<init>(Form.java:181)
at com.codename1.ui.Form.<init>(Form.java:172)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:288)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:275)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:248)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:994)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:793)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:746)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:711)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:652)
at com.codename1.ui.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:807)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:983)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

The line marked with ** .. ** is my annotation as this is the method of the *Form* class that throws the error.
Either when I open a new form, a dialog (which inherits from Form) or just anything that involves creating a new Form, this issue occurs, at random.

I have no idea how to debug this, as it seems that it is not my code that is causing the issue.

Any tips for debugging or even solving the issue?

**EDIT**

the error is not only limited to the creation of forms, but can also occur when internalizing objects. See stacktrace:

```
<same as above stacktrace after Class.newinstance>
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:690)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:668)
at com.lequi.ep.dtos.ChatDTO.internalize(ChatDTO.java:47)
at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:693)
```

**EDIT 2**

with a lot more testing this issue, I found a single pattern so far. no matter which form or dialog I create, it depends on the number of times I instantiate them. At exactly the 13th time I want to instantiate a form (no matter which screen), this error pops up. I dont have to do anything, just opening the screen and going back. Relevant code snipped with which the error can be reproduced:

```
// main form activity 
<omitted for brevity>
chatButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    new ChatScreen(this).show();
});

public ChatScreen(Form origin) {
    super("Chat", new BorderLayout());
    setUIID("ChatHistory");

    getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> {
        origin.showBack();
    });
    <omitted for brevity>
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a test case for this issue?

Comment: Did you use an API like `LookAndFeel.setMenuBarClass`? That API should have been deprecated and removed

Comment: Francesco, unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the issue and I have not yet found any pattern which is even causing this error.

Shai, I dont use any APIs or other specialties. I just use the CN1 Webservice, connecting to a Postgres via Hibernate, if that helps to narrow down the scope.

Comment: Further infos that I found out just now added in above post.

Comment: Any possible updates? As of now, i cannot deploy this CN1 app, as it crashes after switching screens 13 times. Thats possibly a minute or so max

Comment: I'll need the source code of `ChatDTO` to update this further as there are many pitfalls with externalization. Also make sure you register these objects early on and don't load them in static initiliazers etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting up a second dev environment, importing my git project one to one, without any issues and also noting that this error does not happen on the mobile device itself, the issue can be limited to my specific environment.

I still dont know why this occurs, but the impact is neglectable.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because you didn't invoke `Util.register()` early enough in the code. Notice that you shouldn't do that before the `init(Object)` callback.

However, if you read/write objects before that's invoked (e.g. as a result of a static initializer) will produce an exception like that.

Other potential problems include code that returns `getClass().getName()` instead of a hard coded string. This can fail badly due to obfuscation. The first step is looking at line 47 of `ChatDTO`. What's the object that's read at that line and why?

Also who invokes `at com.codename1.io.Util.readObject(Util.java:693)` and when is it invoked?

The object doesn't read itself.